# Trying to make a game but it recognizes wrong

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a game where you first need to make a deck with. The problem is that when people add cards that dont exist, it wont say that the card doesnt exist. I tried to fix this, but everything I tried doesnt work. I am on discord.js v12. my code is:

```
const cards = [
  `Miner`,
  `Fighter`,
  `Skipper`,
  `Finder`,
  `Bomber`,
  `Master of an Element`,
  `Master of all the Elements`,
]

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("card1")) {
    let deckSlot1 = message.content;
    deckSlot1 = deckSlot1.substring("card1".length, deckSlot1.length);
    if (!deckSlot1) return message.channel.send("You didnt include a card!")
    console.log(deckSlot1)
    if(deckslot = cards) {
      message.channel.send(`Your first card is${deckSlot1}`)
      console.log("In there")
    } else if(deckslot != cards) {
      message.channel.send("That card doesn't exist?")
      console.log("Not in there")
    }
    
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at [`<Array>.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, you are trying to check [equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (don't forget to use double equal when you want to verify an equality else it's an assignation) between an array and a string, instead you could check if the array has the string.

Exemple for your case:

```js
if(cards.includes(deckSlot1)) {
  // It's a card
else {
  // It's not a card
}
```

Comment: Now it just goes to the else function, even though I used miner as card

Comment: Accordingly to your code, you need to not put an espace between `'card1'` and your card name.

Comment: Else you can replace `"card1".length` by `"card1".length + 1`.